# pcolormesh/imshow alternative with one-dimensional non-equally-spaced array?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I'm currently doing a loop over many quantities and creating colormaps using `pcolormesh`.

I'm not using imshow because I have unequally spaced points, and I believe `imshow` cannot do that (the x are time instants, and I have irregular measurements and regions without points - but the time should be in the "correct" place). For example (the black "lines" are actually points that indicate each "box"):

[image: unequally-spaced points with pcolormesh]

My problem with `pcolormesh` is that sometimes, I end up with single lines (i.e., 1 x N arrays) - and in that case, `pcolormesh` does not show any color. Here is a simple example (adapted from [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/pcolormesh_grids.html)) for `pcolormesh` with equally spaced points:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

nrows = 1
ncols = 5
Z = np.arange(nrows * ncols).reshape(nrows, ncols)

x = np.arange(ncols)  # note *not* ncols + 1 as before
y = np.arange(nrows)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(x, y, Z, shading='auto', vmin=Z.min(), vmax=Z.max())


def _annotate(ax, x, y, title):
    # this all gets repeated below:
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    ax.plot(X.flat, Y.flat, 'o', color='m')
    ax.set_xlim(-0.7, 5.2)
    ax.set_ylim(-0.7, 3.2)
    ax.set_title(title)

_annotate(ax, x, y, "shading='nearest'")
plt.show()
```

For `nrows = 2` and `nrows = 1`, I get:

[image][image]

Is there any way/function where I can also plot 1D arrays as colorplots? (`contourf` also requires 2D arrays...)

Comment: So you are trying to create an image with some points distributed in a 2D space `(x,y)` with values `Z`?

Comment: yes, basically the position of the point is given by (x,y) and the color is given by z.

Comment: My current workaround was to duplicate the last line, and then set the ylim to one less unit.

Comment: You might find `plt.scatter(x=x, y=y, c=Z)` helpful!

Comment: That was a good point, but in that case, I'd need x and y to be of the same size. This means, I'd have to plot each line separately, I guess. And the final figure would be quite heavy (with pcolormesh, I can use `rasterized=True`).